# Is it possible to rollback a CREATE EVENT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, events, transactions, rollback

My transaction's sql statements look something like this:

1. Begin a transaction with `START TRANSACTION`
2. Create a record in `TEST` table
3. Start a mysql event with `CREATE EVENT`, using that record's id.
4. Update a `TEST_2` table
5. Commit the transaction with `COMMIT`

Of course, if it fails, then I do a `ROLLBACK`, but after testing, I noticed that the newly created `EVENT` isn't getting rolled back to nonexistence.
I then found out that `CREATE EVENT` triggers an implicit `COMMIT`, in here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/implicit-commit.html

**So, is there any way I can automate the event rollback process? Or somehow make it so that the event gets rolled back if the transaction fails?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May triggers do the job? Triggers are designed to execute in response to a specific event that occur in the database. 
[Oracle Trigger reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm)

Comment: Like creating a trigger that triggers on CREATE events, and if on CREATE EVENT the event's ID doesn't have a matching record (because of the rollback), delete that event?